# How come there isn't a tag for questions regarding investors or VCs?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Well as the title says, how come there isn't a tag for questions regarding investors or VCs?

Comment: A lot of those might be a better fit on [startups](http://startups.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Why would that be limited to startups?  Large companies also have investors, publicly or privately trade.  Does Workplace limit itself to those who wouldn't deal with it?

Comment: Because the workplace is about navigating the workplace environment not about investing and starting a business.  questions about managing a company are on topic but how they get investmetns would be off topic.

Comment: @Chad how do you figure?  VC negotiations impact the workplace just the same as any other topic on here.

Comment: Well then feel free to ask questions if a new tag is warrented for a question it will get added.

Comment: Yes? I did? Can someone put this as an answer already?  I said @RichardU was correct in what he was saying in Lillienthal's answer and I asked if he could put that as answer.   Your welcome to too Chad, as far as I know at least.

Answer (score 8):

Because we have no questions justifying their creation.

- [Venture Capital](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22venture%20capital%22%20is%3Aq): 2 closed questions, none open
- [Venture Capitalists](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22venture+capitalists%22+is%3Aq): 1 question created by OP today, potentially off-topic
- [VC](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22VC%22%20is%3Aq%20closed%3Ano): no open questions (one unrelated)
- [Investor](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22investor%22%20is%3Aq%20closed%3Ano): 1open question, feels off-topic to me

Tag should never be created in advance. Only create them when they are useful. Generally that requires the expectation that multiple questions will be asked about that topic in future. Existing questions that can have the tag added aren't strictly required but a good indicator that a tag would be useful.

Comment: How would VCs/Investors be off topic?  There is no rule excluding questions on this as far as I'm aware?

Comment: Here's my VC question, how is this off topic? http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/66167/negotiating-with-venture-capitalists-while-employed-elsewhere

Comment: @JeffQuick Not having a tag does not mean it's off topic, simply that the topic is not frequently addressed or addressed enough to justify creating a tag for it.  Ask enough questions and it might earn a tag

Comment: @RichardU Ok that's fair.  Want to make that an answer?

Comment: @JeffQuick Whether the entire subject is off-topic has no relevance to the question of whether a tag should be created. I've expanded my answer to clarify the conditions for tag creation (as I see them). My search filters were too strict to catch your question, whether that's on-topic is not that relevant to this meta question.

Comment: @Lilienthal care to elaborate? All I got from that was confusion on what you're trying to say.

Comment: @JeffQuick This meta question is asking why there is no tag for VC. Whether or not your question (that could potentially be tagged as [tag:VC]) is on-topic or not does not matter for this meta question.

Comment: Yes I agree.  So your point is?

Comment: By that logic, your answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @JeffQuick Feel free to think that, but I suggest reading it again as you don't seem to understand what I'm getting at.

Comment: @JeffQuick "Q:Why don't we have a tag X? A:We don't have enough questions or expectation of future questions about X to justify it."  I think you are trying to pick a battle about VC relations being on topic and are missing the point that On/Off topic is not the driver for tag creation.

Comment: @Myles I'm not picking battles.  That would be Lilienthal.  I already asked 2 other people if they could make  "A:We don't have enough questions or expectation of future questions about X to justify it." They answer if you look through the other comments.

Comment: @JeffQuick You realise that that's basically what my answer says as well?

Comment: @Lilienthal where does it say that?  Your answer is wordy and confusing beyond the list.